# Arduino/Python Serial Error 'can't open the device '\\.\COM5': Access is denied

Tags: python, arduino, port

I'm trying to make a face tracking camera w/ python & Arduino using OpenCV.  I'm having trouble with the serial getting this error:

> 'avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "\.\COM5": Access is denied.'

I'm not sure how I can prevent this. It won't run if the python program is already open, if I open Arduino then python it will run but won't work.

```py
import cv2
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM5',baudrate = 52000)

def detectface(camera):
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(camera)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 480)
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 640)
    faceDetect = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
    print(cap.isOpened())

    while(cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        face = faceDetect.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
        for(x, y, w, h) in face:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 2)
            center = [(x+x+w)/2, (y+y+h)/2]
            center[0] = int(center[0])
            center[1] = int(center[1])
            if(center[0]<235):
                ser.write(b'x')
            elif(center[0]>245):
                ser.write(b'w')
            if(center[1]>335):
                ser.write(b'h')
            elif(center[1]<305):
                ser.write(b'y')
            cv2.circle(frame,(center[0],center[1]),25,(0,0,2),3,8,0)
        cv2.imshow('face', frame)
        if(cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q')):
            break
    cap.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


detectface(0)
```

```
#include <Servo.h>
char tiltChannel=0,panChannel=1;
char serialChar=0;
int center1;
int center2;

char pyInput;
Servo servoTilt, servoPan;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(52000);
  servoTilt.attach(9);
  servoPan.attach(10);
  servoTilt.write(90);
  servoPan.write(90);  
}

void loop() {
  int currentRotationX = 90;
  int currentRotationY = 90;
  if(Serial.available()>0){
    pyInput = Serial.read();
    if(pyInput == 'x'){
      servoTilt.write(currentRotationX++);
      currentRotationX=currentRotationX++;
    }
    else if(pyInput == 'w'){
      servoTilt.write(currentRotationX--);
      currentRotationX=currentRotationX--;
    }
    if(pyInput=='y'){
      servoTilt.write(currentRotationY++);
      currentRotationY=currentRotationY++;
    }
    else if(pyInput == 'h'){
      servoTilt.write(currentRotationY--);
      currentRotationY=currentRotationY--;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: On which step you get that error? Remember that you can't program your Arduino or open its Serial Monitor while your Python code is running.

Answer (score 0):

first try to open the arduino IDE and see on there if your board was detected in some COM Port. if you see on there that there is a com port open, copy it and paste it in your code. 
If you are using anaconda try to install serial with this way:

```
conda install -c anaconda pyserial
```

And  try i.g:

```
ser = serial.Serial('COM10', 9600)
```

Best regards.

Comment: your computer is not recognising the com ports, try to install the driver of arduino.

Comment: the arduino works if I'm just using the arduino command, it just doesn't work with the serial.  I installed the arduino drivers and its still not able to speak to python through serial